# No printers are installed with .Net app use network printer

Tags: c#, printing, report, reportviewer

I have a problem with my .Net application (winform). I installed network printer and then select it as default printer.

I tested with notepad or excel, no problem.

But sometime, my .net app throw InvalidPrinterException with "No printers are installed." on production environment.

When a computer has this error (PC1), i run the app on another pc (PC2) which connected to the same printer, print a report successful and then i re-print on PC1, the error disappear.

The problem also solved when i restart the PC.

Could anyone help me?

Below is call stack (with PrinterSettings.PrinterName = null):

```
System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: No printers are installed.
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal(String printer)
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmodeInternal()
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode()
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings.get_PaperSource()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportViewerUtils.DeepClonePageSettings(PageSettings pageSettings)
```

Here is my code, i'm using Microsoft ReportViewer:

```
PageSettings pageSettings = null;

        try
        {
            pageSettings = this.GetPageSettings();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_NamePrinter))
                pageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = null;
            else
                pageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _NamePrinter;

            pageSettings.Margins = new Margins(_DataSource.PrintInfo.Margin.Left, _DataSource.PrintInfo.Margin.Right, _DataSource.PrintInfo.Margin.Top, _DataSource.PrintInfo.Margin.Bottom);
            pageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", widthPage, heightPage);
            pageSettings.Landscape = _OrientationPrinter;

            try
            {
                int psize = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(PaperKind), printInfo.PaperSize);
                pageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = psize;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            this.SetPageSettings(pageSettings);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogManager.LogError($"Exception: {e.Message}.\n PageSetting detail: {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pageSettings)}");
            throw;
        }
```

The exception will be throw at the line: this.SetPageSettings(pageSettings);

Thanks,
Hien.

Comment: The error is probably occurring because the printer is off-line.  Many of the print drivers test the status of the printer when the are called up.  Your application has to be able to handle the printer being off-line and when the exception occurs either wait for printer to come back on-line or give proper message to users.

Comment: Hi jdweng, at the same time this issue happen, I use MS Excel to try print a test sheet and it's ok. Or another PC also run my app can print on this printer successfully.

Comment: You are setting the Printer Name to null and then continuing to print.  Once you set the  name to null you should not continue.  The code posted isn't the code that gets the Printer Name so you should find the code that is getting the printer name.

Comment: Hi jdweng, in case the user doesn't choice any printer to print, then printername will be set is null, it mean was print by a default printer of PC.

Comment: So how can you set the printer settings if you do not have a null printer?  When you restart the PC do you set a default printer?  Do you get to this code when you restart the the PC?  A PC always has a default printer so can you get the default printer name and use it?